# curl request to HTTParty request

Tags: api, curl, httparty

I have very little experience with APIs can someone please help me translate this:

```
$ curl -X POST -d "login_id=myemail@email.com&api_key=231421423423423423423" \
  https://devapi.testapi.com/v2/authenticate/api
```

to something like this?:

```
include HTTParty
base_uri 'https://devapi.testapi.com'

def login
  response = self.class.post( "/v2/authenticate/api",
               :headers => { "login_id" => 'myemail@email.com', "api_key" => '231421423423423423423' }
             ).parsed_response

  @token = response["auth_token"]
  return @token
end
```

I'm not sure where to put login_id and api_key so that they would appear at the beginning of the request address instead of the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to clear up some confusion. When you send a POST request, like you did with Curl, it looks like this:

```
POST /v2/authenticate/api HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
Host: localhost:8000
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 56
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

login_id=myemail@email.com&api_key=231421423423423423423
```

The first line is the request method (`POST`) and resource (`/v2/authenticate/api`) and the protocol version (`HTTP/1.1`). The next five lines are the headers, which always have a key (e.g. `Content-Length`), followed by a colon and space (`:`), followed by a value (`56`).

You'll notice that none of these headers have your data, i.e. `login_id` or `api_key`. Data doesn't go in the headers. It goes in the body, which is after the headers and an intervening blank line that tells the server, "the headers are done; everything else I send is the body."

Hopefully that will help clear up the confusion that I see here:

> I'm not sure where to put login_id and api_key so that they would appear at the beginning of the request address instead of the end.

In a POST request the data is not part of the address, nor is it, to reiterate, part of the headers. It's the body.

When making a POST request with HTTParty, you could use the `:body` option to specify a string to use as the POST body, but in your Ruby code it looks like you'd rather use a Hash, which is the right way to go. With a Hash, you use the `:query` option instead of `:body`, and HTTParty will automatically encode the Hash's contents correctly. Using that, your code would look like this:

```ruby
query_hash = { :login_id => 'myemail@email.com',
               :api_key  => '231421423423423423423' }

response = self.class.post("/v2/authenticate/api", :query => query_hash)
```

Comment: Wooohooo, thank you for the explanation, this is definitely going to be useful in the future. btw it worked ! :)